# Why would re-sharper suggest using implicit typing when I already know the type in c#?

Tags: c#, types

Consider a standard initialization:

```
Person p = new Person();
```

Visual studio is suggesting changing this code to

```
var p = new Person();
```

Why would I do this? I would expect my program is more readable if the type is explicit.

Comment: The behavior is neither of C# or Visual Studio.

Comment: In your example yes and I would agree. It's arguably more useful for verbose types such as `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, DateTime>>> y = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, DateTime>>>();` simplified as `var x = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, DateTime>>> ();`.  Plus its jolly good for _anonymous types_